# user login authentication SingleOrDefault() or FirstOrDefault() which one to use

Tags: performance, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing a user login authentication. I make LINQ query like this:

```
var v = db.AppUsers.Where(a=>a.USERNAME.Equals(appUser.USERNAME) && a.PASSWORD.Equals(appUser.PASSWORD));
```

Now I've to store the username, id and role in session variables. For this, what should I use,

```
 var v = db.AppUsers.Where(a=>a.USERNAME.Equals(appUser.USERNAME) && a.PASSWORD.Equals(appUser.PASSWORD)).FirstOrDefault();

     or SingleOrDefault().
```

Please suggest which one to use SingleOrDefault() or FirstOrDefault(). **Which is the fastest and more optimized**?

Note that USERNAME is unique here.

Comment: I very much doubt there's a performance difference to be found here. Note that SingleOrDefault will throw an exception if the result contains more than one item -- so that *may* be an additional check that needs to be made internally in it. The amount of time these take to run is massively insignificant compare to the time it will take your `Where` to run.

Comment: Yes, this is not a question about which is faster, it's a question about *which best fits the expected outcome?* If you ever expect to have more than one user with the same username, you should use `FirstOrDefault()`. If you want it to be an *error* that more than two people have the same username, you should use `SingleOrDefault()`

Comment: also i hope to god you're not storing your password as plaintext, because it looks like you are. This is a **MASSIVE** security risk!!!!!!

Comment: @DLeh Yes I am not storing password as plain text. It is only a sample case. Thanks for the suggestion!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between `FirstOrDefault` and `SingleOrDefault` is what they do after retrieving the data from RDBMS:

- `SingleOrDefault` checks if there is more data, and throws an exception if there is a second row
- `FirstOrDefault` simply returns the first row

If the row is guaranteed to be unique, then from the performance standpoint, you would save a dozen CPU cycles or so by using `FirstOrDefault`. The operation being heavily dominated by RDBMS timing, however, it is rather unlikely that you would see any difference.

On the other hand, from the readability standpoint the retrieval of a unique record should look like a retrieval of a unique record, rather than the retrieval of a first record. Using `SingleOrDefault` has two advantages:

- It tells your readers that the record must be unique, and that otherwise it's an error
- It checks at runtime that there is at most a single record, and alerts you if your logic is broken.

That is why I would use `SingleOrDefault` - being extra careful is worth more than dozen CPU cycles.